# Second call to MPI_Bcast sending old data from first call

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, mpi

I have run in to a very odd bug, where calling MPI_Bcast is sending out the wrong value. When I check the value being sent in the root process, it prints out the correct value, but in all the other tasks it prints the old value.

I have tried looking up similar issues, but all of the results came up with people either not calling Bcast on all tasks, or trying to use it where gather would be better suited.

Since the Bcast is not sending the correct data out, my lower tasks end up stuck in an infinite loop. Using ^C allows it to exit properly, but I need to implement the code to exit on its own. (which it should be doing if Bcast would behave)

Shortened version of the code:

```
include statements
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
variable declarations here
 MPI is initialized up here 
        if (rank ==0)
        {
                input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
                output = fopen("fakeOutput.txt", "w+");
                while(1)
                {
                        count = 1; //reset counter
                        if(exitFlag)  break; 
                        command = (char*)calloc(89,sizeof(char));
                        command[0] = '.';
                        command[1] = '/';
                        batLine = (char*)calloc(86,sizeof(char));
                        for(i=0; i < 16; i++) 
                        {
                                if(fgets(batLine,86,input) != NULL)
                                {
                                        if(loopCount> 0)
                                        {
                                                Continue = true; 
                                             MPI_Bcast(&Continue,1,MPI_C_BOOL,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                                        }
                                        if(i==0)
                                        {
                                                strcat(command,batLine);
                                                printf("rank0 gets: %s\n", command);
                                                fflush(stdout);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        { 
                                                MPI_Send(batLine,85,MPI_CHAR,i,i,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                                                printf("sent rank%d: %s\n",i,batLine);
                                                fflush(stdout);
                                                count++;
                                         }
                                else
                                {
                                        Continue = false;
                                        exitFlag = true; //flag to break out of while loop
                                        free(batLine);
                                        batLine = (char*)calloc(86,sizeof(char));
                                        batLine[0]='e';
                                        MPI_Send(batLine,85,MPI_CHAR,i,i,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                                 }
                        }
                        free(batLine);
                        //system(command);      ///to run batch file line
                        delay(500); //to simulate time of the command running
                        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
                        fprintf(output,"%s", command); //rank 0 has first spectrum
                        free(command);
                        outputFile = (char*)calloc(33,sizeof(char));
                        for (i=1; i<count;i++) //task 0 doesn't send data. have to start at 1
                        {
                                MPI_Recv(outputFile,33,MPI_CHAR,i,16,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat2);
                                printf("rank 0 recieved data from %d\n",stat2.MPI_SOURCE);
                                fflush(stdout);
                                fprintf(output,"%s\n",outputFile);
                                printf("Data:%s\n",outputFile);
                        }
                        MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                        printf("continue after barrier:%d\n",Continue);
                        free(outputFile);
                        loopCount ++;
                        if(exitFlag)
                        {
                                Continue = false;
                                MPI_Bcast(&Continue,1,MPI_C_BOOL,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                                printf("sent:%d\n", Continue);
                                break;
                        }
                fclose(input);
                fclose(output);
                printf("files closed\n");

        }
        else
        {
            while(1)
            {
                command = (char*)calloc(89,sizeof(char));
                sentbatch = (char*)calloc(86,sizeof(char));
                spectrum = (char*)calloc(33, sizeof(char));
                command[0] = '.';
                command[1] = '/';
                MPI_Recv(sentbatch,86,MPI_CHAR,0,rank,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&stat);
                printf("rank%d was sent data from%d\n",rank,stat.MPI_SOURCE);
                fflush(stdout);
                if(strncmp(sentbatch,"e",1) == 0)
                {
                        noSend = true; //don't want to send back the place holder data
                }
                strcat(command,sentbatch); //adds needed ./ before batch data
                 free(sentbatch); //don't want to waste memory space
                //system(command); //should run batch line
                Switch statement to give different delay times to different tasks here
                MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                 if(noSend == false)
                {
                        for(i=0; i<31; i++)
                        {
                                spectrum[i] = command[i+13];
                        }
                        free(command);
                        fflush(stdout);
                        printf("sending:%s\n",spectrum);
                        fflush(stdout);
                        MPI_Send(spectrum, 33,MPI_CHAR,0,16,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                        free(spectrum);
                }
                MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                MPI_Bcast(&lowContinue,1,MPI_C_BOOL,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);
                fflush(stdout);
                printf("continue: %d\n",lowContinue);
                if(lowContinue == false)
                        break;
            }
           printf("end for rank%d \n", rank);
        }
        MPI_Finalize();
        printf("closed mpi");
        return(0);
}
```

I am copying the code out of a putty window, so if there are any missing brackets, assume that they are present. They all match in the code itself but copying from nano and putty is the worst.

I know it may look odd initially, but the rank 0 loop starts over before the lower ranks, so BCast ends up being called 2 times for all tasks with the input file I am testing it with. The code is being run across 16 tasks with only 26 lines to pass around.

There are no errors to show, but here is the end of the statements printed out with duplicate lines removed:

```
rank 0 recieved data from 9
Data:spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-042
continue after barrier:0
sent:0
continue: 1 (present 15 times)
files closed
```

The file that fgets is scanning:

```
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-001.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-003.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-004.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-005.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-006.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-008.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-008.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-010.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-010.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-013.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-013.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-015.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-015.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-018.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-018.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-022.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-022.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-023.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-023.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-024.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-024.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-025.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-025.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-028.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-028.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-029.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-029.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-030.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-030.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-031.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-031.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-032.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-032.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-033.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-033.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-035.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-035.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-037.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-037.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-038.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-038.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-039.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-039.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-040.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-040.nor f
LAMOSTv108 spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-042.flx spec-56321-GAC099N59V1_sp01-042.nor f
```

Also, yes, I use Continue as a variable even though I technically shouldn't. It is capitalized so it is different from continue and because I like having variable names that make logical sense. (or I end up using the dumbest names possible for everything)

Comment: Are you sure you want to `MPI_Bcast()` in the `for(...; i < 16)` loop?

Comment: fwiw, your code would be much simpler if you `MPI_Send()` and `exit` command to all the tasks rather than broadcasting a condition.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Yes, I want the BCast within that for loop. It only ever is called after the first while loop (kept track of with loopCount), and I need it to be only when the file has more lines. To be able to split up the lines properly I have the get the next file line within the for loop.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet As for using MPI_send, that is my back up solution if bcast won't work. This is part of a control program for another program that normally takes a year to run. Using another for loop to be able to use send would slow it down more than bcast from my understanding of bcast. This part of the code will be run at least 126,592 times with the current data, and even more times next year when new data is available. For now I will be using Send and recv just to be able to keep working, but I am hoping someone knows why bcast is acting up and can answer the question.

Comment: you missed my point. Simply get rid of one `MPI_Bcast()` per line, and send one `exit` line to each slave **after** there is no more line to read. your current algorithm with `MPI_Bcast()` is wrong because bcast, send and recv calls do not match between master and slaves, look at what would happen on rank 1 if your input files has 16 lines: how many times do master calls `MPI_Bcast()` and `MPI_Send(dst=1)`? how many times rank 1 calls `MPI_Bcast()` and `MPI_Recv(src=0)`?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet You are right about it breaking with 16 lines of input. I think if I fix that the rest will be fixed. I didn't notice the issue as none of the files will have only 16 lines. As for calling exit, isn't that the same as calling break for my code at the end of the slave task loop?

Comment: Similar issue with let’s say 31 or 32 lines. By `exit` I mean sending a “special” command that will `break` the slave loop instead of being executed.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet All of the files should contain more than 16 lines and less than 31. I got bcast to send correct data but something is still hanging up the slaves. I am pretty sure fixing the 16 line issue will also fix the hang up though so thank you for pointing that out! It is not easy to trouble shoot simple loop mistakes with no debugger to help

Comment: You can stop hardcoding `16`, use the number of MPI tasks and debug with 2 and then 3 and finally 16 tasks. Note `printf` based debugging should be enough here.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I got it working now, so thank you. I am hard coding the tasks to 16 as another program will be hard coding to start it with 16 total tasks. So checking the number of tasks isn't needed as for the final code the user will not be calling mpiexec at all. That way the user doesn't ever need to actually understand all the options available for mpiexec.